# Windshield frame rusting

Tags: rust, windshield, cracking

Our car (Honda Accord) did not pass inspection due to a cracked windshield. we have full glass insurance, but when Safelight came to our home and inspected the car they informed us that the windshield frame was rusted, and the windshield would not be covered. Is it worth repairing the rusted frame, is there any way to repair a rusted frame?

Comment: I'm sure the rusted part could be cut out and a salvage piece welded in and then refinished.  You didn't state the model year of the car but it's likely such a repair would exceed the value of the car.  It might be time to find a newer model that can pass inspection.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt it can be repaired ( reasonably ) if it needs any mechanical integrity. For a specific part like that there are two choices : a Honda dealer or a salvage/junk yard.